# ¿Porque este codigo de ordenacion en burbuja no funciona?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Cuando ejecuto el programa, los números salen desordenados, ¿podrían decirme cual es el error en el código?

**Lenguaje**: c++

**Librerías**: 
iostream, string, cstdlib, ctime

**Sistema operativo**: Debería funcionar en cualquier plataforma

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
int chaar[5];//matriz a ordenar
int fnum;
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
   srand(time(0)); //genera números aleatórios para la matriz
   for(int i = 0;5>i;i++){
     fnum = rand()%100;
    chaar[i]=fnum;
   }

   for(int i = 0;i<30;i++){
    int b36;
    int b=i-1;
    if(chaar[i]<chaar[b]){
      b36 = chaar[i-1];
      chaar[i-1]=chaar[i];
      chaar[i]=b36;

    }
   }

   for(int i =0;i<5;i++){ //imprime la matriz
    cout<<chaar[i]<<" ";
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hay errores como que si haces b=i-1, comenzará valiendo -1 y ya tendrías un acceso a array fuera de límite. Por otra parte el algoritmo burbuja no te ordena todo el array en una sola iteración del bucle. En cada iteración lleva un solo elemento "al final" del array, pero tienes que iterar muchas veces, cada vez con un array un poco más corto, hasta que esté ordenado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No se por que tenias el valor de: `i<30;` puesto que tu longitud de tu
>   matriz era de 5 (`int chaar[5];`), quedando de esta forma el primer for: `for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){` otra cosa es el
>   algoritmo de burbuja normalmente se realiza con dos bucles, en
>   tu algoritmo solo había un bucle(`for`). El algoritmo quedaría de esta
>   forma:

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
    int b36;
    int b=4;
        for (int j = 0; j< b; j++){
            if(chaar[j]<chaar[j+1]){
              b36 = chaar[j];
              chaar[j]=chaar[j+1];
              chaar[j+1]=b36;

            }
        }


 }
```